# Why does a string with 300 in it compared against a string with 1000 in it return false in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, conditional-statements

In my React project I am currently filtering data by price, using the min and max. In my max price conditional I check if the max price is empty or if not I check to see if the price for the current data can pass the filter

```
( !this.state.max_price.trim() || listing.price <= this.state.max_price )
```

I noticed that it will work when entering a max price for every number that doesn't exceed 1000, but as soon as a number 1000 or higher was entered it failed, and return false so I tested out the conditional in jsfiddle to see if I was missing something. Below I got an unexpected result

```
// I put this in jsfiddle, and it returned false 
if ("300" <= "1000") {
  alert('true')
} else {
  alert('false')
}
```

I also put this code below in jsfiddle and was met with a result I expected (as you can see it is working for numbers below 1000 but not 1000 and above)

```
// I put this in jsfiddle, and it returned false 
if ("300" <= "500") {
  alert('true')
} else {
  alert('false')
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you are comparing strings, and "300" is lexographically greater than "1000"

```js
console.log("300" < "1000");
console.log(300 < 1000);
```

Comment: convert it into an number using parseInt()

Comment: is it better to use parseInt() or Number() ?

Comment: would your your number have a decimal point ? If it is just an Integer use parseInt

Answer (score 1):

In string comparison in JavaScript (mostly any language), strings are compared by their ASCII values, and since the ASCII value for `"3"` (51) is greater than that of `"1"` (49) `51>49` hence `"300">"1000"`.  
You can convert the string variables to numbers using the unary `+` oprator `+"1" => 1`:

```js
var a = "300";
var b = "1000";
if (a <= b) {
  console.log('true')
} else {
  console.log('false')
}
a = +a; // convert to number using the unary '+' operator
b = +b;
if (a <= b) {
  console.log('true')
} else {
  console.log('false')
}
```